# Can clone method create object using constructor

Tags: java, clone

I always thought that `clone()` creates an object without calling a constructor.

But, while reading Effective Java **Item 11: Override clone judiciously**, I found a statement which says that

> The provision that “no constructors are called” is too strong. A
>   well-behaved clone method can call constructors to create objects
>   internal to the clone under construction. If the class is final, clone
>   can even return an object created by a constructor.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: `clone()` method not calls constructor, its default behavior is it will perform shallow copy. but if we want to perform deep copy we need to override `clone()` method , from which we can return new Object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I always thought that clone() creates an object without calling a constructor.

The implementation in `Object.clone()` doesn't call a constructor.

There's nothing to stop you from implementing it yourself in a way which does. For example, this is a perfectly valid `clone()` implementation:

```
public final class Foo implements Cloneable {
    private final int bar;

    public Foo(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

You can only do this (unconditionally) if the class is `final`, because then you can guarantee to be returning an object of the same type as the original.

If the class isn't final, I guess you *could* check whether the instance was "just" an instance of the type overriding `clone()` and handle it differently in different cases... it would be odd to do so though.

Comment: Why can I only do this if the class is final? If i do this in non-final class, will there be any kind of impact?

Comment: @Anand: `clone()` has to return an instance of the same type as the original. If the class is non-final, you have to consider the possibility that `this` will refer to an instance of a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I think below part of code always create the new object and supply to the other class (i.e. helpfull in singleton).

```
 @Override
    public Object clone() {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
```

I think this can be supply for the purpose:

```
public MyObject clone() {
    return new MyObject(this);
}
```